# How to get new emails automatically using Microsoft Graph in a UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-graph-api

I have successfully connected to Microsoft Graph using OAuth. I can receive and send emails from my Office365 account.

But I am completely stuck on how to receive emails automatically, similar to the IMAP IDLE routine.

I am referencing

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Services.MicrosoftGraph;
```

I have tried Subscription but have no clue what to do next, or even if this is correct.

```
Subscription sub = new Subscription {
    ChangeType = "created",
    NotificationUrl = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
    Resource = "/users/me/messages",
    ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(20),
    ClientState = "????" // if applicable, what is this
};
```

Answer (score 4):

To make a subscription you need to expose a notification URL with https (see [graph documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/webhooks)).

> ```
> POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
>  Content-Type: application/json
>  {
>    "changeType": "created,updated",
>    "notificationUrl": >  "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/notificationClient",
>    "resource": "/me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages",
>    "expirationDateTime": "2016-03-20T11:00:00.0000000Z",
>    "clientState": "SecretClientState"
>  }
> ```

If you want examples the [graph documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/webhooks) references a [Node.js](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample) and [asp.net](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-webhooks-rest-sample) example. Both use ngrok to expose an https URL (just for testing purposes though). The program tunnels HTTP requests through to your localhost (like a reverse proxy). If you have that setup, you have to validate your request. When you send your subscription request the first post message your notification URL will receive is a message with a validation token (see [doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/webhooks)). You have to send this validation token back. Now you should receive notifications on your specified notification URL.

You can read about the Subscription resource type and its properties in the [graph documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscription).
For example, the client state is described as:

> Specifies the value of the `clientState` property sent by the service in each notification. The maximum length is 255 characters. **The client can check that the notification came from the service** by comparing the value of the `clientState` property sent with the subscription with the value of the `clientState` property received with each notification.

Comment: Many thanks both for filling in the fields, I need to go down the json call route. It will take me a while to do this; but your answer looks the correct method and the only way to achieve what I need. But I understand it 95% now.

Comment: @peterincumbria Is there any additional information you need (missing 5% :D)? If it's about receiving notifications on your localhost you can use HttpClient in C# .net for example.

Comment: Still struggling with this on UWP. I cannot find any UWP sample code which does not help. All the UWP sample code and Nuget packages avoid "Subscriptions". I may need to raise more questions on SO when I return to the PC later in the week.

Comment: The major issue is that the asp example is not helpful for a UWP app. It has to be something to do with the syntax of the notification URl, I cannot find any information on this at all. I may need to resort to background polling for new emails which is not a tidy solution.

Comment: It's definitely the syntax of the notification URL. You can't use the redirect URL you got at app registration.    > This URL has to make use of the HTTPS protocol.(see [link to doc of Subscription resource type](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscription)).

Comment: The notify URL would need to be within the company network, that means the firewall will most likely block the incoming request. Hey, I have it working fully now by using the streaming notification.

Comment: If need any code I am quite happy to share.Have a great day.

Comment: Thank you, you too.

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions are not in possible at this moment using Microsoft Graph for UWP, for notifications the Outlook 365 API should be used. The Microsoft graph api can be used for Auth and other tasks though.

Can Microsoft consider including streaming notifications in Microsoft Graph?